# minikube hostpath mount permissions

Tags: macos, kubernetes, permissions, minikube, persistent-storage

I'm trying to mount a local directory to be used by a container in kubernetes, but getting this error:

```
$ kubectl logs mysql-pd

chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Input/output error
```

minikube version: v0.33.1

docker for mac version: 2.0.0.2 (30215)

Engine: 18.09.1

Kubernetes: v1.10.11

I'm starting up minikube with mounted directory:

```
minikube start --mount-string /Users/foo/mysql_data:/mysql_data --mount
```

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mysql-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: mysql:5.7
    name: mysql-container
    env:
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      value: ""
    - name: MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
      value: "yes"
    ports:
      - containerPort: 3306
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
      name: host-mount
  volumes:
  - name: host-mount
    hostPath:
      path: "/mysql_data"
```

Comment: Why is it important that you store the actual database files on your (HFS|APFS) filesystem? Are you going to run a separate `mysqld` pointed at that same directory later? Because the sane thing to do is just omit that `--mount` business and let `hostPath:` do what it normally does and write into the virtual machine's disk, which is still _local_ to you, and subject to Time Machine et al, but side-steps this entire debate

Comment: So far, hostPath has not worked for me, neither has PersistentVolume or any other technique or suggestion I can find out there.  This is the closest I've come to a meaningful error message. I would like to persist the database beyond the lifetime of the container.

Comment: Are you deleting minikube, because that's the only outcome through which a `hostPath:` or PV would delete outside the lifecycle of the Pod

Comment: You're right, I guess I was thinking it would make its files on my hard disk.  There they are inside the VM.  Still, I wish it would behave like Docker.  In Docker I can launch the mysql container and have the database files stored on my hard drive

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to create a shared folder in VirtualBox that can also be written to by the kubernetes pod. I'm guessing that would be another permissions error

Comment: As for why it's important - it'll just be a bit less confusing for developers who may be using the docker container locally, and then have to maintain two separate database installs if they also use the kubernetes configuration

Answer (score 2):

As  @Matthew L Daniel mentioned in the comments, the main purpose of using [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) is to mount a local folder from your machine which is hosting minikube inside to the nested Pod, therefore it's not necessary to mount local directory inside to minikube. Also, take a look at this [article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/#mounted-host-folders) which explains some restrictions about host folder mounting for the particular VM driver in minikube.

Comment: I'm fine with that if it will work.  I have tried everything to get the database files to persist and so far absolutely nothing works.  This is the closest I've gotten to a meaningful error message.  I'm hoping it will lead somewhere useful.